# How is my Game Loop?

Tags: java, game

I wrote a game loop for a game I'm going to be making:

1. Check the current FPS
2. Try the keep the FPS to a hardcoded level
3. Draw and Update the game.

There are two classes, the abstract class and the implementing class.

Any suggestions?

**`Game`**

```
public abstract class Game {
    private int FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
    private boolean running = true;
    long targetTime;

    private long runningFPS;

    protected Game(int fps) {
        setTargetFPS(fps);
    }

    public void setTargetFPS(int fps) {
        this.FRAMES_PER_SECOND = fps;
        targetTime = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
    }

    public void run(JPanel panel, BufferedImage image) {
        int currentFPS = 0;
        long counterstart = System.nanoTime();
        long counterelapsed = 0;
        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;
        targetTime = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;

        while (running) {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            processInput();
            update();
            // time to update and process input
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start; 
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            if (hasTimeToDraw(wait)) {
                //CREATE AND ANTIALIAS GRAPHICS
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                g.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                //Draw
                draw(g);
                g.dispose();
                panel.repaint();
                //Take account for the time it took to draw
                elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
                wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            }
            counterelapsed = System.nanoTime() - counterstart;
            currentFPS++;

            // at the end of every second
            if (counterelapsed >= 1000000000L) {
                //runningFPS is how many frames we processed last second
                runningFPS = currentFPS;
                currentFPS = 0;
                counterstart = System.nanoTime();
            }

            //dont wanna wait for negative time
            if (wait < 0)
                wait = 0;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public long getCurrentFPS() {
        return runningFPS;
    }

    private boolean hasTimeToDraw(long wait) {
        //Not really sure how to implement this method... Maybe just time the draw method and hardcode it in?
        return true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public abstract void processInput();

    public abstract void update();

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);
}
```

**`GameFrame`**

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 800;

    private JPanel panel;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    private Game game = new Game(60){
        int i = 0;
        int x = 5;

        @Override
        public void processInput() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void update() {
            GameFrame.this.setTitle("FPS: " + getCurrentFPS());
            if(i > WIDTH || i < 0)
                x = -x;

            i += x;
        }
        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(i, 50, 20, 53);
        }

    };

    public GameFrame(){
        panel = new JPanel(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void run(){
        game.run(panel,image);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GameFrame().run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long start;
long elapsed;
long wait;
```

This is no Pascal, declare your variable where they get initialized. This is not always possible, maybe 1 such variable per 10 classes is unavoidable.

```
        //dont wanna wait for negative time
        if (wait < 0)
            wait = 0;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Better don't change a variable if you don't have to as it makes the code harder to understand. Doing

```
Thread.sleep(wait<0 ? 0 : wait);
```

is simpler, doing

```
Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, wait));
```

is even simpler and so is

```
if (wait>0) Thread.sleep(wait);
```

The main problem is that your method is far too long. Extracting some methods would help a lot, e.g.,

- `Graphics2D g = newNiceGraphics(image);`
- `sleepUninterruptibly(wait);`

Enough for now....

Answer (score 3):

Reserve all capital names to static final constants. It seems that a better name instead of `FRAMES_PER_SECOND` would be `targetFPS`.

Also, this variable can be final, because you assign it once, though this is not clear immediately. It becomes clear when you reorganize the constructor and get rid of the pointless `setTargetFPS` method, like this:

```
private final int targetFPS;

protected Game(int fps) {
    this.targetFPS = fps;
}
```

`targetTime` doesn't need to be a member variable: although you set it in the constructor, you don't use that initial value, and then you overwrite it in the `run` method. So change that from a member variable to a local variable in the `run` method.

In the `run` method, if you don't want to wait for negative time, then don't! Instead of overwriting the value of `wait`, use conditionals. It's also pointless to wait for 0 time:

```
if (wait > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(wait);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

In `GameFrame`, the `image` and `panel` fields can be `final`. In general, make member fields `final` if possible. Non-editable things are inherently robust and lead to safer code.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep()` is a bad call which can lead into many problems. I was told to never use it. instead I will show you the way I do my game loops. It might not be the perfect game loop but it is good.

I recommend implements runnable and putting your loop in your run method.

```
public void run(){

    init(); //initialisation of images, sound..etc. will be executed once only

    int fps = 60 //number of update per second.
    double tickPerSecond = 1000000000/fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    while(running){

        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime)/tickPerSecond;
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1){

            tick();
            render();
            delta--;
        }
    }
}

private void init(){

  //initialisation image, sound, loading world, generate maps....etc
}

private void tick(){

  //tick player, world, entities..etc
}

private void render(){

  //render graphics.  
}
```

Also don't forget to create `start` and `stop` methods for the thread. You can change the fps to what number you would like, no need to go higher than 60.

Explanation why thread.sleep() is a bad call: [click-here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/)

Its not that important but its better also if you gonna make 3d-game and using physics which requires accuracy in timing.

Comment: This would be a better answer with more explanation of why `Thread.sleep()` is bad.  A link wouldn't hurt, but you should include at least one example of a problem caused by `Thread.sleep()` in the post itself.